# Error opening webcam

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller

I used this code. The webcam opens once, after that it shows a black screen. Also I want to store captured images in a database.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.webcam.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="webcam"></div>
<a href="#" id="upload">Capture image and send for processing</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pos = 0, ctx = null, saveCB, image = [];
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', 320);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', 240);
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    image = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 320, 240);
    var saveCB = function (data) {
        var col = data.split(';');
        var img = image;
        for (var i = 0; i < 320; i++) {
            var tmp = parseInt(col[i]);
            img.data[pos + 0] = (tmp >> 16) & 0xff;
            img.data[pos + 1] = (tmp >> 8) & 0xff;
            img.data[pos + 2] = tmp & 0xff;
            img.data[pos + 3] = 0xff;
            pos += 4;
        }
        if (pos >= 4 * 320 * 240) {
            ctx.putImageData(img, 0, 0);
            $.post('@Url.Action("Uploadimage","Home")', { type: 'data', image: canvas.toDataURL("image/png") }, function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    alert('The image was successfully sent to the server for processing');
                }
            });
            pos = 0;
        }
    };

    $('#webcam').webcam({
        width: 320,
        height: 240,
        mode: 'callback',
        swffile: '@Url.Content("~/scripts/jscam.swf")',
        swffile: '@Url.Content("~/scripts/jscam_canvas_only.swf")',
        onSave: saveCB,
        onCapture: function () {
            webcam.save();
        }
    });

    $('#upload').click(function () {
        webcam.capture();
        return false;
    });
</script>

home controller 

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Uploadimage(string image) {
  image = image.Substring("data:image/png;base64,".Length);
  var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(image);
  // TODO: I am saving the image on the hard disk but
  // you could do whatever processing you want with it
  System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/app_data/capture.png"), buffer);
  return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

The output

[image]